# Why do two queries run faster than combined subquery?

Tags: postgresql-11

I'm running postgres 11 on Azure.

If I run this query:

```
select min(pricedate) + interval '2 days' from pjm.rtprices
```

It takes 0.153 sec and has the following explain:

```
    "Result  (cost=2.19..2.20 rows=1 width=8)"
    "  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
    "    ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..2.19 rows=1 width=4)"
    "          ->  Index Only Scan using rtprices_pkey on rtprices  (cost=0.56..103248504.36 rows=63502562 width=4)"
    "                Index Cond: (pricedate IS NOT NULL)"
```

If I run this query:

```
    select pricedate, hour, last_updated, count(1) as N 
    from pjm.rtprices
    where pricedate<= '2020-11-06 00:00:00'
    group by pricedate, hour, last_updated
    order by pricedate desc, hour
```

it takes 5sec with the following explain:

```
    "GroupAggregate  (cost=738576.82..747292.52 rows=374643 width=24)"
    "  Group Key: pricedate, hour, last_updated"
    "  ->  Sort  (cost=738576.82..739570.68 rows=397541 width=16)"
    "        Sort Key: pricedate DESC, hour, last_updated"
    "        ->  Index Scan using rtprices_pkey on rtprices  (cost=0.56..694807.03 rows=397541 width=16)"
    "              Index Cond: (pricedate <= '2020-11-06'::date)"
```

However when I run

```
    select pricedate, hour, last_updated, count(1) as N 
    from pjm.rtprices
    where pricedate<= (select min(pricedate) + interval '2 days' from pjm.rtprices)
    group by pricedate, hour, last_updated
    order by pricedate desc, hour
```

I get impatient after 2 minutes and cancel it.

The explain on the long running query is:

```
    "Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=3791457.04..4757475.33 rows=3158115 width=24)"
    "  Group Key: rtprices.pricedate, rtprices.hour, rtprices.last_updated"
    "  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
    "    ->  Result  (cost=2.19..2.20 rows=1 width=8)"
    "          InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
    "            ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..2.19 rows=1 width=4)"
    "                  ->  Index Only Scan using rtprices_pkey on rtprices rtprices_1  (cost=0.56..103683459.22 rows=63730959 width=4)"
    "                        Index Cond: (pricedate IS NOT NULL)"
    "  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=3791454.84..4662729.67 rows=6316230 width=24)"
    "        Workers Planned: 2"
    "        Params Evaluated: $1"
    "        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=3790454.81..3932679.99 rows=3158115 width=24)"
    "              Group Key: rtprices.pricedate, rtprices.hour, rtprices.last_updated"
    "              ->  Sort  (cost=3790454.81..3812583.62 rows=8851522 width=16)"
    "                    Sort Key: rtprices.pricedate DESC, rtprices.hour, rtprices.last_updated"
    "                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rtprices  (cost=0.00..2466553.08 rows=8851522 width=16)"
    "                          Filter: (pricedate <= $1)"
```

Clearly, the last query has it doing a very expensive gathermerge so how to avoid that?

I did a different approach here:

```
    with lastday as (select distinct pricedate from pjm.rtprices order by pricedate limit 3)
        select rtprices.pricedate, hour, last_updated - interval '4 hours' as last_updated, count(1) as N 
        from pjm.rtprices
        right join lastday on rtprices.pricedate=lastday.pricedate
        where rtprices.pricedate<= lastday.pricedate
        group by rtprices.pricedate, hour, last_updated
        order by rtprices.pricedate desc, hour
```

which took just 2 sec with the following explain:

```
    "GroupAggregate  (cost=2277449.55..2285769.50 rows=332798 width=32)"
    "  Group Key: rtprices.pricedate, rtprices.hour, rtprices.last_updated"
    "  CTE lastday"
    "    ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..1629038.11 rows=3 width=4)"
    "          ->  Result  (cost=0.56..105887441.26 rows=195 width=4)"
    "                ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..105887441.26 rows=195 width=4)"
    "                      ->  Index Only Scan using rtprices_pkey on rtprices rtprices_1  (cost=0.56..105725202.47 rows=64895517 width=4)"
    "  ->  Sort  (cost=648411.43..649243.43 rows=332798 width=16)"
    "        Sort Key: rtprices.pricedate DESC, rtprices.hour, rtprices.last_updated"
    "        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..612199.22 rows=332798 width=16)"
    "              ->  CTE Scan on lastday  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=4)"
    "              ->  Index Scan using rtprices_pkey on rtprices  (cost=0.56..202957.06 rows=110933 width=16)"
    "                    Index Cond: ((pricedate <= lastday.pricedate) AND (pricedate = lastday.pricedate))"
```

This last one is all well and good but if my subquery wasn't extensible to this hack, is there a better way for my subquery to have similar performance to the one at a time approach?

Comment: You probably want to run `explain (analyze, buffers)` and see that with the subquery in the predicate Postgres cannot make an accurate estimate of matching rows and resorts to `Seq Scan`. See if disabling parallelism helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea

```
Select pricedate, hour, last_updated, N from (
    select pricedate, hour, last_updated, count(1) as N
         , dense_rank() over (order by pricedate) as rnk
    from pjm.rtprices 
    group by pricedate, hour, last_updated 
) 
WHERE rnk <= 2
order by pricedate desc, hour
```

Assuming all pricedates are dates, i.e. at midnight